# Issue regarding cursor styling for a disabled button by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application I am using some javascript on one of my view page to make a submit button with id "submitorder" disabled. And I have done this successfully using the following line of code.

```
 $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', true);
```

It is working fine.

But now I want to make the cursor as 'not-allowed' also when hovering on that submit button. That's why I have used the following lines of code to make the submit button disabled and as well as to make the cursor as 'not-allowed'

```
$('#submitorder').prop('disabled', true);
$('#submitorder').css( 'cursor', 'not-allowed' );
```

But unfortunately the button becomes disabled only. There is no change in the cursor styling.

Please tell me why this is happening and give me clues to figure out this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps it gets overwritten by the stylesheet? And speaking of the stylesheet, this is rather where you should place this in the first place - using the attribute selector.

Answer (score 1):

Add/remove a CSS class:

```
.not-allowed { cursor: not-allowed; }
```

Note: cursor: none; not supported until Firefox 3, Safari 5, and Chrome 5. Not at all supported in IE or Opera. Image URL cursors not supported in Opera. The following not supported in IE or Opera: not-allowed, no-drop, vertical-text, all-scroll, col-resize, row-resize.

You can also have the cursor be an image:

```
.custom-not-allowed {
     cursor: url(images/not-allowed-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btn=document.getElementById('yourId');

btn.setAttribute('disabled',true);
btn.style.cursor='not-allowed';
```

```html
<input id="yourId" type="button" value="disabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting `css('cursor', 'none')`

```js
$('#submitorder').prop('disabled', true);
$('#submitorder').css('cursor', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="submitorder">submit</button>
```